# What's the Swift 2.0 equivalent to parse.com's signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:()?

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I got the follow error when attempting to build a parse.com project via Xcode 7.0/Swift 2.0:

[image]

Is there a work around for this?

What's the Swift 2.0 equiv.?

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: ObjCBool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // do something
}
```

Or

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { succeeded, error in
    // do something
}
```

--

Note, Xcode can show you the appropriate types. For example, if I start to type and then let code completion show me the method, I see something like:

[image]

If I then hit enter and select the `block: PFBooleanResultBlock?` and hit enter again, I'll see:

[image]

That shows me precisely what types those two parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {success, error in
        if error == nil {
            //
        }
        else{
            //
        }
    }
```

Above works fine with no errors.